# Operator does not exist: tstzrange && timestamp with time zone

Tags: postgresql

Running:

```
SELECT tstzrange( '2019-05-01', '2019-05-09' ) && '2019-05-01'::timestamptz
```

I get error message:

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: tstzrange && timestamp with time zone
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

**Why there is no range overlap with a point?**
This operation looks reasonable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why there is no range overlap with a point?

Because this is not how "overlaps" is defined. If you want to test if a single timestamp value falls into a range, you need to use the contains operator `@>`

```
SELECT tstzrange( '2019-05-01', '2019-05-09' ) @> '2019-05-01'::timestamptz
```

Comment: currently implemeted as [next](http://paste.scsys.co.uk/585257), but **why "overlaps" does not define intersection with a point?** Probably maillist discussions

Comment: @EugenKonkov: Well, the standard [overlaps](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#id-1.5.8.14.6.1) operator is also defined in that way.